# Listing nested json values by respective headers : Python Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am trying to normalize a nested json response from this [URL](http://data.corkcity.ie/api/3/action/datastore_search?id=6cc1028e-7388-4bc5-95b7-667a59aa76dc). As it is quite nested, i am not able to achieve the following format, can anyone help me in right direction?

[image: Target Format]

I am using this approach to normalize:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import  pandas as pd
class jsonResp():

   def __init__(self):
       global data
       global data1
       global path
       pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
       pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
       pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
       requestURL = ("http://data.corkcity.ie/api/3/action/datastore_search?id=6cc1028e-7388-4bc5-95b7-667a59aa76dc") #Request urls for json
       responseOpen = urlopen(requestURL)
       elevations = responseOpen.read() #Reads the response
       data = json.loads(elevations) #Loads the json file for normalization and parsing
       df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_normalize(data), orient='columns')
       print(df)


if __name__ == '__main__':
   obj = jsonResp()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by navigating to the records and then use `json_normalize()`:

```
import requests
json_data = requests.get("http://data.corkcity.ie/api/3/action/datastore_search?id=6cc1028e-7388-4bc5-95b7-667a59aa76dc").json()

from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

df = json_normalize(json_data["result"]["records"])
```